# Keep imported modules from showing up in code completion?

Tags: python, python-2.7, autocomplete, python-import

How can I keep imported modules from being accessible (i.e., clogging my code-completion options)?

For example:

```
# testmodule.py

import os

def o_stuff():
    return
```

When I import `testmodule`, I don't want `os` to show up every time I type `testmodule.`; I only want the functions/classes declared within testmodule – in this case, just `o_stuff`.

Is there something similar to the asterisk (i.e., `from testmodule import *`) that will do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a special variable `__all__` containing a list of the names to be imported by `from module import *` - for example:

```
# testmodule.py

import os

__all__ = ['o_stuff', 'more_stuff']

def o_stuff():
    pass

def more_stuff():
    pass
```

IDEs with code-completion will typically also respect `__all__` (though I'm unfamiliar with Visual Studio, so I don't know whether IntelliSense does so).

An alternative, included here for completeness although I would **strongly recommend** against it (on the grounds that it'll annoy anyone reading your code to distraction) is to import modules as an underscore-prefixed alias:

```
# ugly_as_sin.py

import os as _os

def o_stuff():
    return _os.name
```

Again, both `from module import *` and, typically, code-completion will ignore underscore-prefixed names.

Comment: D'oh, by 3 seconds!

Comment: where did you read Visual Studio or IntelliSense? It's not in the question nor in the tags

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the `__all__` in your module to see if it helps.

```
import os

__all__ = ['o_stuff']

def o_stuff():
    return
```

Not familiar with Intellisense but it sounds like it could also use a bit of fine-tuning.

Comment: Where did you read IntelliSense? It's not in the question nor in the tags

Comment: I read "autocomplete" and assumed IntelliSense.