# Python autocomplete ignores __all__ and private imports

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm, python-import

I am curious how VSCode/PyCharm autocomplete decides on which members to show when importing a module. Here is a stylized example:

```
# dependency.py

def use_dependency():
    pass


# manager.py

from dependency import use_dependency as _use_dependency


__all__ = ["get_stuff", "write_stuff"]


def get_stuff():
    return "stuff"


def write_stuff(stuff):
    print(f"Writing {stuff}")


# main.py

import manager
manager._use_dependency()
```

In the example above, I would expect `manager` only to show public members when it is imported in `main.py`. However, both VSCode and PyCharm also show `_use_dependency` which was marked as private.

On the other hand, we I look at something like `random` module, it also marks all imports as private and defines `__all__`:

```
from warnings import warn as _warn
from math import log as _log, exp as _exp, pi as _pi, e as _e, ceil as _ceil
from math import sqrt as _sqrt, acos as _acos, cos as _cos, sin as _sin
from os import urandom as _urandom
from _collections_abc import Set as _Set, Sequence as _Sequence
from itertools import accumulate as _accumulate, repeat as _repeat
from bisect import bisect as _bisect
import os as _os
```

but none of those are suggested in the autocomplete. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509012/hide-external-modules-when-importing-a-module-e-g-regarding-code-completion), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755836/keep-imported-modules-from-showing-up-in-code-completion) and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/214329/importing-modules-for-private-use-in-python) it seems that the strategy with prefixing imports as private and defining `__all__` should work, and it does for some modules but not for others.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here with VSCode and am not sure how to tackle this. In custom modules it doesn't work, but it seems to respect the `__all__` symbol from builtins, such as `pathlib`